# Date Concatenation VBA

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate but it is not working

```
Dim i As Integer
          For i = 2 To lastRow
          If Not IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(i, 17).Value) Then
            With wsFinal
                .Cells(i, 17).NumberFormat = "#"
                .Cells(i, 17).Value = "01/01/" & wsFinal.Cells(i, 17).Value
            End With
       End If
       Next i
```

For example, if I have a number stored as text (1949) I am trying to change the format to number which is not a date so it can be looped through. Then I want to add that year to 01/01/xxxx. CAn anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: What results do you get? what results do you need?

Comment: Oh it just adds 1/1 to all of the empty rows as well this is a problem..

Comment: Your setting the cell to a number format (`#`) explicitly then overwriting the value with a date, set a date format `.Cells(i, 17).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`

Comment: I would rather use something like: .Cells(I, 17).Value = DateSerial(.Cells(I, 17).Value, 1, 1)
Excel should be able to interpret the value as a date by itself so there may not be a need to set the format anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `dd/mm/yyyy` Number format. # is for Number values.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Not IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(i, 17).Value) Then
        With wsFinal
            .Cells(i, 17).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Cells(i, 17).Value = "01/01/" & wsFinal.Cells(i, 17).Value
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

Also make sure `wsFinal.Cells(i, 17)` actually returns a year.

**IsEmpty** is not a function for testing values. It is more about testing variables, like Arrays or objects to see if they are initialized.

Example is,

```
Dim iCtr 
Debug.Print IsEmpty(iCtr)   '<- Will Print True
iCtr = Null
Debug.Print IsEmpty(iCtr)   '<- Will Print False
```

In the above example, we have initialized the variable `iCtr` as Null, although on a common world it is still not a value, it still is initialized. So `IsEmpty` will not yield the right result. It might be better to test with `IsNull`. However `Zero Length String` are not really Null, so `IsNull("")` will fail, when `iCtr = vbNullString`. So in hindsight, `IsEmpty` and `IsNull` might not do the trick.

What I said about using **IsDate** (*make sure `wsFinal.Cells(i, 17)` actually returns a year*) is, if you test `IsDate("Happy")`, the result is going to be False, so the condition you are checking will Pass as it is `Not IsDate("Hello")`, so make sure it is returning a number and not `Hello` or some other string, which is not a Date.

In conclusion, take extra care which function you use. I would recommend a `Not IsDate` followed by a `IsNumeric`

Comment: If Not IsDate(wsFinal.Cells(i, 17).Value) and if Not IsEmpty(wsFinal.Cells(i, 17).Value) 

is there something wrong with this statemetn?